# Is it possible to customize PayPal's authorization forms for web applications?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

In order to design a seamless web application, it would be perfect to have control over the design (CSS) of the authorization interfaces of PayPal.
Is this customization -next to for native mobile application development- also possible for web applications?

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do is setup [Custom Payment Pages](https://www.paypal.com/customize) from within your PayPal profile or provide the custom page parameters in your API requests.

This will allow you to set a custom logo, adjust header colors, border colors, etc. but that's about it.